# Add working Link to MS Teams Conversation using Microsoft Flows

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I've set up a ms flow so email text to a group get added to a MS Teams Conversation and any attachments get saved to the relevant Channels Sharepoint folder. However  I also want the email attachments to be visible on the conversation. I can get the file link to show in a comment, using a separate 'When File is Created (Properties only)' trigger in a second flow. However it doesn't have a hyper link to the file.

How can I add a working link to the file to the conversation using flows?

Comment: Why aren't you using the channel email address and sending email to the channel directly? All of the file handling is done for you automatically.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT I'm not using the channel email address as it's a random character string (followed by the domain), which I can't really expect people to remember. The Team email address is much easier.

Comment: There is a way to have a more user-friendly email address for a channel if you are using Microsoft Exchange for email. It's manual to set up, but it works. If you only need to do this for a few channels it works well. Let me know if you want the details. The feature you're asking for is actually a Flow feature.

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT Yes please, that would be great if you could let me know how to set it up. Many thanks.